# Can't get vertical images

Tags: jquery, function, height, width, each

I'm using the following code to get vertical images and add class to it but, I don't know why, is not working:

```
    //wrapall div inside a container
    $('#page_container .et_pb_column_1 .et_pb_module').wrapAll('<div class="slider-pag_interna">');

    //for each img I check height and width and assign some classes
    $(".slider-pag_interna div span img ").each(function(){
        
        if ($(this).width() < $(this).height()) {
          $(this).parent().parent().addClass("vertical");
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("horizontal");
        }
        
    });
```

My html code:

```
<div id="page_container" class="et_pb_row et_pb_row_0 et_pb_row--with-menu" style="z-index: 3;">
        <div class="et_pb_column et_pb_column_1_2 et_pb_column_1  et_pb_css_mix_blend_mode_passthrough et-last-child">
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_image et_pb_image_0">
                <span class="et_pb_image_wrap "><img loading="lazy" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/Af0sF2OS5S5gatqrKzVP_Silhoutte.jpg?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGljfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="" width="auto" height="auto"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_image et_pb_image_1">
                <span class="et_pb_image_wrap "><img loading="lazy" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/Af0sF2OS5S5gatqrKzVP_Silhoutte.jpg?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGljfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="" width="auto" height="auto"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_image et_pb_image_2">
                <span class="et_pb_image_wrap "><img loading="lazy" src="https://www.threebu.it/wp_threebu/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/vertical-farming-chris-jacobs.jpg" width="auto" height="auto"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="et_pb_module et_pb_image et_pb_image_3">
                <span class="et_pb_image_wrap "><img loading="lazy" src="https://images.unsplash.com/reserve/Af0sF2OS5S5gatqrKzVP_Silhoutte.jpg?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8M3x8cGljfGVufDB8fDB8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80" alt="" width="auto" height="auto"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My [test page](http://view-source:http://www.jeanclaudechiementin.com/test/bx-slider_vertical_img-test3.html)

Comment: Please include the html/images in the question, ideally in a snippet (edit and click `[<>]`).

Comment: What exactly is not working ? on your test page i do see the correct classes on the `.et_pb_module` container

Comment: Ah - didn't see the *extra* .wrapAll() (**not mentioned here**)   As stated earlier, please include all relevant information **in the question**.   See [mcve].

Comment: Copied code to a jsfiddle - works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/7untm5kh/  As above by @estellechvl opening your page and inspecting the images show they have the classes as expected.

Comment: Your issue is that doc.ready runs **before the images are loaded**.  So as @AkshAyAgrawal notes, the sizes are 0.  When estellechvl and I checked, your code, it (likely) used cached images so there was no loading time.  You need to hook into the image loaded event. `window.onload` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/3698214/2181514

Comment: Check the 3rd image on the fiddle..  It has horizontal class applied to it, but it should have had Vertical class applied to it, as per the intended logic

Comment: @AkshAyAgrawal yes, because the code ran before the image had loaded - for *me* it has the `vertical` class applied.

Comment: yep, freedomn-m is right. so basically wrapping your code into something like `$(window).on("load", () => {});` should do the trick

Comment: OK sorry I added the wrapAll and the html code

Answer (score 1):

Insert all things inside "window on load" function instead of "document ready"  fixed the problem

```
$(window).on('load', function(){

    $('#page_container .et_pb_column_1 .et_pb_module').wrapAll('<div class="slider-pag_interna">');

    $(".slider-pag_interna div span img ").each(function(){
        
        if ($(this).width() < $(this).height()) {
          $(this).parent().parent().addClass("vertical");
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().parent().addClass("horizontal");
        }
        
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Your scripts seem to be executing BEFORE the DOM is rendered, and that is why all width v/s height comparisons in your script are returning FALSE.  Height = 0 and Width = 0 for all elements.

Your Jquery code is placed in the `<head>` tag right now on your test page.
Try moving it to the `<body>` section in your code, and things will work out fine..

Comment: Try debugging it in the Chrome debugger, you'll see the height and width for all images is returned as ZERO.  When I copied over the scripts to the body section, things worked fine.

Comment: I was trying also window on load function but sometimes it did not work maybe it was a cache problem...I was thinking that 'window on load' function was running during loading and 'document ready' was the function for everything after the entire windows contents was loaded... I feel so stupid now...

Comment: So GGKMNTN, Finally how did you fix things ?

Comment: I inserted all things inside "window on load function" instead of  "document ready"